# Sorting a List of Objects with by a number string that is at the end of a string

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, .net-core

I'm having some trouble sorting a list of objects. The problem is that I need to sort it by a number string that is at the end of a string but It's not working.

Here is my sort:

```cs
grades.Sort((p1, p2) =>
{
    Regex regexLanguage = new Regex(@"^[A-Z]*"); 
    var p1Number =  Int32.Parse(regexLanguage.Replace(p1.Subject.SubjectCode, ""));
    var  p2Number =  Int32.Parse(regexLanguage.Replace(p2.Subject.SubjectCode, ""));
    if (p1Number < p2Number)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return -1;
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask]. In particular, please include a [mcve] in your question which we can run.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate on *It's not working*?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add an example

Comment: Also you should not declare the regex every single time within the sort. Get that out of the linq like the line above and use the object within as normal. It will be much faster to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning the full range:

```
Regex regexLanguage = new Regex(@"^[A-Z]*"); 
grades.Sort((p1, p2) =>
{
    var p1Number =  Int32.Parse(regexLanguage.Replace(p1.Subject.SubjectCode, ""));
    var p2Number =  Int32.Parse(regexLanguage.Replace(p2.Subject.SubjectCode, ""));
    return p1Number.CompareTo(p2Number);
});
```

Check [Comparison documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1?view=net-5.0)

> Return Value
>
> Int32 A signed integer that indicates the relative values of x and y, as shown in the following table.
>
> RETURN VALUE
>
> Value  Meaning
> Less than 0   x is less than y.
>
> 0 x equals y.
>
> Greater than 0 x is greater than y.

Comment: Or just `return p1Number.CompareTo(p2Number)`

Comment: You are so right! I updated the answer on the spot!